# Закрыть несколько вкладок сразу

Tags: javascript, вкладки

Ребята, возникла огромная проблема, допустим, есть главная страница, с этой страницы открыли еще одно окно(в новом окне соответственно), а с новой страницы открыли ещё одну страницу, т.е. получилось 3 вкладки, и так можно продолжать сколько угодно, так вот, как закрыть все открытые ранее вкладки с последней открытой вкладки, т.е. в конце концов, чтобы осталась главная страница. Не могу понять как это делается, нашёл решение, когда закрываются страницы с главной страницы, но как это сделать с последней открытой вкладки. Не понимаю, ведь для каждой новой вкладки родительская страница уже другая и как реализовать это закрытие всех вкладок, спасибо заранее за понимание проблемы и её решение.

Comment: я не сталкивался, но если родительская страница может всем управлять, то просто пошлите запрос на родительскую страницу с дочерней, пусть там запустится скрипт =)

Comment: С этим и есть проблемы, не ясно как передать исполнение скрипта на другую страницу

Comment: через сервер ;)

Comment: Ясное дело, это очевидно, само собой

Comment: А если серьезно, как я могу передать скрипт скрипт для закрытия следующей такой же вкладки? Я не могу понять какими средствами это достигается 

 <script lang="JavaScript">
  <!-- hide
  function openWin() {
   myWin = window.open("404.html");
  };
function closeit() {
 closetab = window.close();
};
 </script>
  <div class="content">
   <a href="index.html" onClick="closeIt()" >Перейти к главной странице</a>
   <input type="button" value="Перейти на другую страницу" onClick="openWin()">
   <a href="index.html" onClick="CloseAll()">Закрыть ранее открытые вкладки</a>
  </div>

Comment: для начала: ваш код работать не будет, нужны идентификаторы открытых страниц, тут пример: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close В вашем коде нужно сделать что-то типа myWin.close(); В остальном мой ответ остался прежним: толкаете инфу на сервер, оттуда получаете сигнал на выполнение скрипта и все готово. Правда опрашивать сервер придется слишком часто ну или, как вариант, использовать вебсокет.

Comment: Хорошо, согласен, создаём переменную в которую будет записывать данные, открыть или закрыть открытую страницу, мне не понятно как именно взаимодействовать с сервером, чтобы скрипт понимал, что нужно закрыть, вот что мне не ясно

Comment: главная страница постоянно опрашивает сервер по аякс или вебсокет, когда мы нажимаем закрыть на вторичной странице, то посылаем сигнал на сервер, на сервере меняется переменная, когда в след раз главная страница опросит сервер, она увидит, что переменная поменялась. этого достаточно чтобы привязать какую-то функцию. очень просто. это все равно что парсить цены на сторонних сайтах - та же схема. меня больше волнует вопрос: разрешит ли браузер закрывать вкладки главной вкладке, если она не в фокусе или нет. там могут быть ограничения.